# What is causing my menus, and widgets to be mushed?

Tags: gnome, xfce, gtk

I have switched from Gnome3 to XFCE, and now my gnome applications have mushed menu bars, and widgets don't look right.

gnome-terminal

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tk7Iq.jpg]

gnome-calculator

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8gBZ.jpg]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a theme / style related issue with GTK3. Click your Whisker menu and type "Appearance" and in the "Style" tab, pick a different style. Normally, "Adwaita" works pretty well.

Comment: Works great !! Thank you. I'll accept as answer when I'm allowed to :-)